# lxml._ElementTree.getpath(element) returns "*" instead of tag names for elements in non default name space

Tags: c++, python, xpath, lxml, libxml2

Please help to make `getpath()` to return full tag names in `getpath()` xpath or to find workaround

I'm trying to generate xpath to element in a `lxml.etree._ElementTree`. `ElementTree` is generated by parsing 600Kb response from some production WebService.

```
print elem.getroottree().getpath(elem)
```

Here is result I get:

```
'/S:Envelope/S:Body/ns5:getPhysicalResponse/*[18]/*[12]/*[6]/*[2]'
```

Unfortunately I cannot post original xml - it contains proprietary customer information.
Also I tried to reproduce this result with automatically generated simple element tree that has 100 nested levels, each level having 100 children but without luck - `getpath()` returned xpath with full tag names.

**Update**
Looking into [lxml source code](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/e01a81740c77ddd26f98b316cec4610b2914eb64/src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd#L330) - it points to `tree.h` `xmlGetNodePath` method from the `libxml2` library. So this is actually `libxml2` behavior.

**Update**
Doing more tests I figured out that this happens every time when tag has non default namespace.

Answer (score 1):

use `getelementpath()` and postprocess namespace as you like.

Comment: Huge thanks for this - would have never figured this out